# Get req params in client Javascript

Tags: javascript, url

Say I have a string like

```
http://somerandomwebsite.com/345345/465645456546
```

This string matches the pattern

```
http://somerandomwebsite.com/:userId/:gameId
```

From the above string, how do I extract the userId and gameId values no matter their length(so not substring)

I know in ExpressJS you can do

```js
app.get("/:userId/:gameId", (req, res) => {
var userId = req.params.userId
var gameId = req.params.gameId
})
```

But I need this to work in client side Javascript

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) is a safe and modern method that works server and client side:

`location.pathname` can be used if it is the url of the page you are on

`link.pathname` can be used for link objects

*Say I have a string*  - then you need to make it a URL first

```js
const [_,userID, gameID] = new URL("http://somerandomwebsite.com/345345/465645456546")
  .pathname.split("/"); 
console.log(userID,gameID);
```

Comment: AND location.href too

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.pathname` to get the path name of a url.

```js
window.location.pathname.split('/')
```

Comment: It has to be a URL first